# Trigger Not fired when records updated through data loader

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader

when i update a single record from UI..the trigger fires properly and does it thing but when i use data loader to update 1200 records then trigger is not fired for all records.

The IF condition is getting true but not executing the method when using data loader.

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
   set<Id> sL = new set<Id>();
        for (lead l : trigger.new) {
            if ((l.field0__c != trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).field0__c) 
                    || (l.field1__c!= trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).field1__c) 
                    || (l.field2__c!= trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).field2__c) 
                    || (l.field3__c!= trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).field3__c)) {
                sL.add(l.Id);
            }
        }
        if (!sL.isEmpty()) {

            ClassName.Metod(sL);
        }                                                                   
 }
```

Comment: Does your trigger have any exclusion logic based on an integration or data-load user/profile? Is `ClassName.Metod()` properly bulkified?

Comment: Hi @David Reed  No exclusion Logic. The trigger works well with single record update from UI.  And Yes method is bulkified.

Comment: if data loader transaction size > 200 (you would have to alter this in settings) and you are using some static vbl for trigger recursion control, then records 201+ may not be processed due to static vbl value

Answer (score 2):

This code is properly bulkified, and should work on bulk updates. Note that the trigger only does additional work if one of the four fields are actually updated. Check your data and make sure that records are actually changing.

Comment: Yes...I am changing the the field3__c and yes i can see the record is getting modified using last modified date time

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar != is case-insensitive, by the way, so if you're just changing capitalization, it won't count as a change in this code.

Comment: No i am changing values...like form xxxx to yyyy

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar You're missing something, then, or you've oversimplified the code example. This should work correctly.

Comment: okay..i will use debug.....Initially i thought i made any silly mistake. Thanks for the help